# Delete and nodes with pointers to data?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, nodes

Will `delete`ing a pointer to the struct `foo`:

```
struct foo
{
    bar * baz;
};
```

Pointing to struct `baz`:

```
struct baz
{
    int arr;
};
```

Also `delete`/ free the memory pointed to by `baz`?

Comment: Along with the destructor, you should follow the rule of three/five and implement a copy/move constructor and assignment operator as well.

Comment: Haven't learned about copy constructors as much yet.  It's for a DS class, so we're not getting too far into the language itself.

Comment: If it did, that would be a disaster. What if something else was *using* `struct baz`?!

Comment: Yeah, that was precisely my fear

Answer (score 4):

No. Deletes do not "cascade" in this way.

However, if you have a *destructor* for `foo`, then you could `delete baz` within that destructor.

Answer (score 3):

No.  You would either need to manually delete baz before deleting the instance of foo.  Most typical developers would have the destructor of foo delete baz.

```
struct foo
{
    bar * baz;
    ~foo()
    {
        delete baz;
    }
};
```

Comment: Or better yet, if `baz` is created in the constructor and deleted in the destructor, it probably shouldn't be separately allocated.  (Or otherwise, use a smart pointer.)

Comment: K, thank you.  I have several tables pointing to the same data, so I wanted to make sure deconstructing one table wouldn't affect the actual data.